# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: оператор не существует: ltree ~ ltree

Tags: java, postgresql, mybatis

Я не могу разобраться со странной ошибкой в Postgresql.
В базе есть таблица

```
CREATE TABLE public.mytable(
id BIGINT NOT NULL,
name TEXT NOT NULL,
parent BIGINT NOT NULL,
path LTREE NOT NULL
);
```

Я использую Spring boot + Mybatis Framework.
Мне нужно сделать запрос в базу и получить из этой таблицы потомков 1 уровня.
т.е. что-то типа такого запроса:

```
<select id="getByPath" resultMap="resultMap">
    select * from mytable where path ~ 'root.28.*{1}'
</select>
```

Этот запрос отрабатывает как надо.

Но у меня ведь майбатис, и запрос должен выглядеть так:

```
<select id="getByPath" resultMap="resultMap">
    select * from mytable where path ~ #{path}
</select>
```

На этом запросе летит ошибка:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: оператор не существует: ltree ~ character varying
Подсказка: Оператор с данными именем и типами аргументов не найден. Возможно, вам следует добавить 
явные приведения типов.
```

Добавляю в запрос приведение типов:

```
<select id="getByPath" resultMap="resultMap">
    select * from mytable where path ~ #{path}::ltree
</select>
```

Но все равно вылетает та же ошибка:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: оператор не существует: ltree ~ ltree
Подсказка: Оператор с данными именем и типами аргументов не найден. Возможно, вам следует добавить 
явные приведения типов.
```

Помогите разобраться с этой ошибкой.

Comment: Пробовали вставить ковычки? ~ '#{path}'

Comment: тогда ведь это не будет параметром. я попробовал. с кавычками начинает читать, как обычный текст

Comment: Пробовали &quot; ?

Comment: а это не то же самое? Тоже не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У оператора `~` перегруженного для `ltree` правый операнд типа `lquery`. Так что правильно так:

```
<select id="getByPath" resultMap="resultMap">
    select * from mytable where path ~ #{path}::lquery
</select>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это то,что нужно!!

Answer (score 0):

У вас запрос внутри тега. подстановка делает ваш запрос

```
 select * from mytable where path ~ root.28.*{1}
```

без кавычек. В следствии чего у ваш ошибка оператор не существует.

Попробуйте использовать спецсимволы в запросе

```
"   &#34;

'   &#39;
```

Comment: Попробовал. Ошибка осталась